# Apache rewrite for folder and file inside folder different

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

So I have a folder(Folder1) with 10 files in it(file1-10)

I would like 1 rewrite rule for the folder except if file2 and file8 are accessed. This should have a different rewrite rule.

So RULE1 for just the folder and all files except 2 and 8
RULE 2 for the folder and all the other files.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use [RewriteCond](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) for something like that.

Something like:

```
# General rule for Folder1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/Folder1/file(2|8)$
RewriteRule ...

# Rule for Folder1/file2 and Folder1/file8
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/Folder1/file(2|8)$
RewriteRule ...
```